# Apache Velocity: non-latin names of the custom directives

Tags: java, velocity, directive

how to do custom velocity directive with localized name.
Such directives is ignored now.
For example:

```
class MyDirective extends Directive {
  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "Пример";
  }
  @Override
  public boolean render(InternalContextAdapter context, Writer writer, Node node) 
        throws IOException, ResourceNotFoundException, ParseErrorException, MethodInvocationException {
    writer.write("example");
    return true;
  }
}
```

Input text: `#Пример()`

Expected `example`, but got unmodified text `#Пример()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a velocity parser limitation according to this Identifier definition

```
<PRE_REFERENCE,REFMODIFIER,REFMOD2>
TOKEN :
{
    <#ALPHA_CHAR: ["a"-"z", "A"-"Z", "_"] >
|   <#IDENTIFIER_CHAR: [ "a"-"z", "A"-"Z", "0"-"9", "_" ] >
|   <IDENTIFIER:  ( <ALPHA_CHAR> ) (<IDENTIFIER_CHAR>)* >
    {
        if (curLexState == PRE_REFERENCE)
        {
            SwitchTo(REFERENCE);
        }
    }
}
```